# Best way to handle data attributes in Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, templating, slim-lang

I was evaluating **Slim** as a replacement for **HAML** in a personal project, and it doesn't appear to handle HTML5 data attributes as gracefully as HAML. I was hoping someone may have also run into this, or may have known about an option/syntax I haven't yet found in their docs.

HAML allows you to define [HTML 5 data attributes](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#html5_custom_data_attributes) simply by using nested hashes like so:

`%a{data: {key1: 'val', key2: 'val'}}`

resulting in

`<a data-key1='val' data-key2='val'></a>`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

There are multiple ways in Slim

1. As Hash

   > Attributes which will be hyphenated if a Hash is given (e.g. data={a:1,b:2} will render as data-a="1" data-b="2")
2. Use it directly as "mu is too short" mentioned, quite intuitive.

   ```
   a data-title="help" data-content="foo"
   ```
3. Use Ruby code. I often do this and rarely above.

   ```
   = link_to 'foo', bar_path, data: {a: 'a', b: 'b'}
   ```

Comment: Awesome, **#3** is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't see anything jump out at the docs describing this the way the HAML docs did. Thanks!

Comment: moss, #3 is neither Haml nor Slim but Rails helper :)

Comment: Note if you do `a href="#" data={user_name: 'fred', user_id: 1}` it will translate this to `<a href="#" data-user-name="fred" data-user-id="1"></a>` - this is nothing to do with Rails as you'll see it working in Sinatra apps as well.

Comment: Note that #3 doesn't work for direct div elements like `.container, data: { url: "link", value: "stuff" }` Instead you have to use #2, like `.container[ data-url="link data-value="stuff" ]`

Comment: Just to mention it: Slim is truly beautiful.

Comment: in case you want to separate to multiple lines use: div(data-a="asdf" <you can insert a line break here>data-b="qwer")

Comment: Underscores in a key are not replaced by hyphens since Slim 4.0 (e.g. `data: {user_id: 1}` is converted to `data-user_id="1"`)

Answer (score 3):

Use the **splat** operator:

```
h1#section-title*{'data-url'=>'test', 'data-id'=>'test'} = @project.name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.your-class*{data: {first_attribute: 'first value', second_attribute: 'second value'} }
```

Will produce

```html
<div class="your-class" data-first_attribute="first value" data-second_attribute="second value"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this kind to fix...

```
@products.each do |product|
  .module data-id=product.id
```

It is working for me