# Converting from html to rail

Tags: css, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this link here:

```
<a href="#rating-box" class="login-window">Rate & Commment</a>
```

and I would like to convert this into rails style, maybe something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Rate & Comment', :anchor => "rating-box", :class => "login-window"%>
```

Is it possible to do so?

**Edit 1**

One more question.

When I use

```
<%= link_to "Rate & Commment", comment_path(:post_id => post.id), :class => "post" %>
```

I can pass on some data (in this case, the post id) to the controller and i can use the data by referencing to params.

So if the path becomes a div element, like

```
<%= link_to 'Rate & Comment', "#rating-box", :class => "post" %>
```

can I still pass on data by bracketing it?

**Edit 2**

I have tried to do this in my view:

```
<a href="#rating-box" class="post" data-post_id = '<%= p.id %>'>Rate & Comment</a>
```

However I couldn't retrieve the data in controller with the code below:

```
def create
@comment.post_id = params[:post_id]
end
```

Comment: From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948017/best-way-to-handle-data-attributes-in-slim 

I think my approach can't work... but how can I use approach 2 as stated in that post to pass on multiple variables?

Answer (score 0):

Conversion of the link in rails style is:

```
<%= link_to "Rate & Commment", "#rating-box", :class => "login-window" %>
```

Comment: Documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Comment: I haven't got enough reputation yet to upvote this but it was helpful, thanks!

Comment: From here: stackoverflow.com/questions/18948017/… I think my approach can't work... but how can I use approach 2 as stated in that post to pass on multiple variables?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I have to use this to solve my own problem:

```
<%= link_to "Rate & Commment", fetch_rating_path(:post_id => p.id), :class => "login-window" %>
```